# Scheme - Counting elements in the list

Tags: scheme, racket

I have the following code:

```
(define (howMany list)
  (if (null? list)
      0
      (+ 1 (howMany (cdr list)))))
```

if we do the following: `(howMany '(1 2 3 (4 5)))` we'll get 4 as result. How do I make it so it counts the # of integers in my list. Meaning the same problem will return 5 as answer instead of 4.

Answer (score 5):

You just have to use the standard template to traverse a list of lists:

```
(define (howMany lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) 0)                  ; an empty list has 0 elements
        ((not (pair? lst)) 1)            ; if it's an element, then count it as 1
        (else (+ (howMany (car lst))     ; otherwise advance the recursion
                 (howMany (cdr lst)))))) ; over both the `car` and the `cdr`
```

A shorter and more idiomatic solution would be to use built-in list procedures, like this:

```
(define (howMany lst)
  (length (flatten lst)))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(howMany '(1 2 3 (4 5)))
=> 5
```

Comment: Is this doable without builtin functions like pair and not?

Comment: No, how else can you tell if we found an element? `pair?` and `not` are two primitive, standard functions, there's nothing unusual about using them! If we reorder the conditions we can eliminate the `not`, but you'll need `pair?` or `list?` at some point

Comment: how can you do this with list? instead of pair?

Comment: Actually pair and list seem to work the same way.. however. can you do this with if instead of cond?